# Can Map operator be executed in parallel without waiting previous flow emission?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a long running job (network call) inside a `map` which "delays" the following emissions until the previous map has finished (`mapLatest` is not desired because it cancels previous executions). Is there a way to execute in parallel the code inside a map as soon as a value is emitted.

Probably a snippet of code will explain the idea better

```kotlin
suspend fun main() = coroutineScope {

    val flow = flow {
        repeat(4) {
            emit(it) //fast emission
        }
    }.map {
        println("Loading")
        delay(1000) //this could be a network call
        println("I'm slow")
        it
    }

    flow.collect {
        println("HEY $it")
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to run `map()` for multiple items at the same time or do you mean the producer of items is running in parallel to `map()`?

Comment: The first option. I want to start processing the map as soon as an item has been emitted by the upstream flow rather than wait for the previous map to finish (sequentially). Maybe a bit of context could help. I have a flow which emits visible items of UI each emission is the list of the current visible items and I have to load info from back on every emission, I don't want wait to start processing next emission until the previous work has finished

Comment: One additional question: do you need to keep item ordering or you want to push items downstream as soon as they are mapped?

Comment: as soon as they are mapped would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Kotlin flows don't provide support for concurrent processing at the time of writing this answer (Kotlin 1.8.20). There are some plans and discussion about it since 2019, but it was not yet implemented.

Of course, with full power of coroutines, we can implement it by ourselves. There are multiple approaches: we can use [flatMapMerge()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html) which already provides a concurrent map operation; we can create a flow of deferred values and proces them in async-await style; but for me the best solution is by using a [channelFlow()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html), and by manually launching coroutines and processing the data:

```kotlin
inline fun <T, R> Flow<T>.concurrentMap(crossinline transform: suspend (T) -> R): Flow<R> = channelFlow {
    collect {
        launch { send(transform(it)) }
    }
}
```

Implementation is really simple: for each item collected from the upstream flow, we launch a new coroutine, we transform the item and send the result to the downstream flow. Nice thing about this solution is that it utilizes the dispatcher of the flow collector, so it behaves similarly to other flow operators.

Please note this solution doesn't keep original ordering of items and it doesn't provide a backpressure. Even if we don't consume items from the resulting flow, it will still keep emitting and transforming items.

You can read more about various implementations (ordered, with backpressure, etc.) and future plans here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1147

Comment: It's working, but I'm facing some problems. I have a `runningFold` operator after the concurrentMap to "re-group" / accumulate the concurrent results, but it missed some of the results or gets lost. I think it's a backpressure problem and I though a buffer operator would help (between the `concurrentMap` and the `runningFold`), but it doesn't work. I've tried reading the link you provided to find a solution to this without luck :(

Comment: @iroyo hmm, could you provide a reproducible example, e.g. in the kotlin playground? I think it shouldn't skip items.

Comment: I ended up solving my problem preparing the playground. I wasn't "adding" up the items correctly inside the `runningFold` (stupid mistake). Again thank you for your time! :)